# Using Python to calculate the probability of an output

Tags: python

I'm currently using Python to create a program which will calculate the probability of landing on each square of a monopoly board. So far, I've come up with this code:

```
def monopoly(turns):
    square = 0
    allsquares = []
    while turns > 0:
      roll = randrange(1,7) + randrange(1,7)
      square = square + roll
      if square > 39:
         square = square % 39
      if square == 30:
         square = 10
      allsquares.append(square)
      turns = turns - 1
    return allsquares
```

This successfully outputs a list of numbers corresponding to the squares on the Monopoly board. My next step is to create a list of these squares next to their probabilities, so that it looks like this:

0 = 2.01%

1 = 1.77%

2 = 1.86%

...etc.

I know how to calculate these percentages mathematically. However, I'm not sure how to tally up each instance of a number, so that I know what to divide by the total number of dice rolls. Could someone point me in the right direction here?

(Note that squares like Community Chest and Chance do not affect movement for my version of Monopoly, so there's no need to factor them into this program.)

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want to calculate the actual ratio that a square was landed upon in a particular instance of the game, played for a given number of turns.

Building upon your original code, here is what I came up with:

```
from __future__ import division # for getting a float result from int division
from collections import defaultdict
from random import randrange

TURNS = 150

def monopoly(turns):
    square = 0
    allsquares = defaultdict(lambda: 0)
    while turns > 0:
        roll = randrange(1,7) + randrange(1,7)
        square = square + roll
        if square > 39:
            square = square % 40 # this should be modulo 40 since there are 40 squares
        if square == 30:
            square = 10
        allsquares[square]+=1
        turns = turns - 1
    return allsquares

allsquares = monopoly(TURNS)
print "The actual ratio for landing on each square in %d turns for this particular game instance was:" % (TURNS, )
for i in xrange(40):
    print "square %d - %.2f%%" % (i, 100 * allsquares[i] / TURNS)
```

As you can see, the main change was keeping score of the landed squares in a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#defaultdict-objects) (with a default value of 0) rather than in a `list` in order to support easy counting. Storing the items in a `list` would have forced us to iterate over the list in order to count each square instance (though this could have been easily done with [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#counter-objects)).

Note that your original script contained an error which rendered it impossible to land on square 0, since the modulo was made modulo 39 rather than modulo 40.

Executing the program gives this output:

```
The actual ratio for landing on each square in 150 turns for this particular game instance was:
square 0 - 1.33%
square 1 - 1.33%
square 2 - 2.00%
square 3 - 2.67%
square 4 - 3.33%
square 5 - 0.00%
square 6 - 5.33%
square 7 - 1.33%
square 8 - 2.67%
square 9 - 2.00%
square 10 - 4.67%
square 11 - 2.67%
square 12 - 2.67%
square 13 - 1.33%
square 14 - 6.00%
square 15 - 4.00%
square 16 - 1.33%
square 17 - 1.33%
square 18 - 2.67%
square 19 - 4.00%
square 20 - 4.00%
square 21 - 4.00%
square 22 - 2.00%
square 23 - 2.67%
square 24 - 1.33%
square 25 - 0.67%
square 26 - 2.00%
square 27 - 2.67%
square 28 - 4.67%
square 29 - 4.00%
square 30 - 0.00%
square 31 - 1.33%
square 32 - 2.00%
square 33 - 2.67%
square 34 - 2.00%
square 35 - 1.33%
square 36 - 3.33%
square 37 - 1.33%
square 38 - 3.33%
square 39 - 2.00%
```

Comment: This was an absolutely excellent answer. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Zetland, I'm glad this answer proved beneficial :-) Please consider [up-voting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/173399) it _and_ all other answers that you found helpful, by clicking the large up arrow that is to the left of each answer. Moreover, please consider [accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) it, _or_ any other answer that solved your problem, by clicking the check-mark that is to the left of the preferred answer. Note that while you may up-vote several answers, you may accept only one. There is absolutely no obligation to do any of these.

Comment: Thanks, I upvoted both answers, although I wasn't sure whether I was experienced enough to mark one answer as the 'correct' one. Following your comment, I will though.

Comment: @Zetland, as the poster of the question, you are free to accept whichever answer that suited you best. In fact, I suggest you browse your latest questions and accept answers that solved your problem, though feel free to leave some questions with no accepted answer if you feel no answer deserves to be accepted. Also, don't feel obliged to accept the most up-voted answer.

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on what kind of probability you want to calculate.  For example, if you're talking about the `P(land on square X | currently on square Y)`, then you would need to keep track of every pair (starting location before a roll and ending location after a roll)...but I'd also like to point out that this can be done without simulation.  It can be calculated analytically as you know the probability of each outcome of a dice roll.

Ex1 `P(land on square 25 | currently on square 1) = 0`

This is impossible without a chance card or something that re-directs you

Ex2 `P(land on square 3 | currently on square 1) = 1/36`

The only way this happens is a roll of snake eyes

If you're talking about a steady-state probability, which I think you are, I would suggest looking for the number of turns you landed on square `X` after a roll and divide that by the total number of turns you took and run your simulation for a long time (this can actually be done analytically as well if you make a Markhov chain)

**Edit** Based on your comment of keeping track of the number of times each square was landed on I would use a dictionary

```
from collections import defaultdict
allsquares = defaultdict(int) #this makes the default value of the dictionary 0

#...whenever a square is landed on
allsquares[square] += 1 #increments that entry in the dictionary by 1
```

To examine the number of times you landed on square 5 for example

```
print allsquares[5]
```

Comment: This is correct. So, if I wanted to know the probability of landing on Square 1, I'd have a formula like: # rolls where I landed on 1 / total # rolls.


 However, the bit I'm struggling with is totalizing the amount of times each square is landed on. Any chance you might know how to do this?

Comment: @Zetland see edit in my answer for a way to count the number of times you landed on any given square